# How can I set up the media file selector for an image with the image styles in the same row?

Tags: 7, media

What I want to do is this:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Formatter Field](https://drupal.org/project/formatter_field) module to choose an image style per entity

> The formatter field module provides a mechanism for specifying a formatter and formatter settings to be used for displaying a field, on a per-entity basis. By default, Drupal provides formatters and settings per entity bundle, but in certain situations it is necessary to choose the formatter at the entity level.

But I don't think anything exists to choose a formatter per *delta* of a field. You'd probably need to look at coding that one yourself. The Formatter Field module would be a good place to start to get ideas for the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am really beginning with this, it will be very hard for me to code something, anyway I will look into this module, thanks again!